# Does Fry's unusual parentage ever effect him adversely?

Tags: futurama

Fry is his own Grandfather, [however that works](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2751/3804). I know that his brain has [saved the world before](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Why_of_Fry#Continuity), a fact that has come back over several episodes.

Was this sort of continuity ever invoked over Fry's parentage or weird genes?

Answer (score 7):

Fry is an [idiot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNWjgz3O6Ws). Isn't that an adverse effect of XTREME INCEST. (The X makes it sound cool)

"Alcohol makes you stupid." - Dwight

["No I'm... doesn't." - Fry](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJPg26Wn_3M)

Comment: I never thought his idiocy was linked to his lineage. Do you have any evidence? Also its not incest if they're not your mother yet....</technicality>

Answer (score 2):

The strength of Fry's power (lack of delta brain waves) is also his downfall.  Because he doesn't produce delta brain waves, he doesn't think the same way every other intelligent being in the Futurama universe does, and it leads to him being an idiot.  You could say that this continuity is invoked every time they make a "Fry is stupid" joke.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Have another look. I'm asking about his reciprocal lineage, not his lack of Delta wave.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage: This actually exactly answers the question. In the episode [The Why of Fry](https://theinfosphere.org/The_Why_of_Fry), one of the Nibblonians says this to him: "...your immunity is due to the fact that you lack the delta brainwave. It's a genetic abnormality which resulted when you went back in time and performed certain actions which made you your own grandfather."